hair particle make instances real question
As far as I know, this function is to make what is made of a particle system into a separate object
enter link description here
When I merge an object made of make instruments real like the video with ctrl + j
Weirdly, the object that was registered as an instance object of the particle system
It has an effect. Why is this?
How can I keep it from moving like this?

the link is private and doesn't work. It requires a login.

I modified the link. Thank you
